# Barcode checker program list index error

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that lets the user enter a barcode and quantity and check it against a text file containing barcodes, quantities of product and product descriptions.

The exact test file looks like this but without the spaces in between each line.

```
12345678,imac,1049.00

12345670,macbookpro,1749.00

11111111,iphone,599.00

22222222,macbook,1249.00

87654321,ipadPro,549.00
```

My code doesn't always work. E.g if you enter '11111111' as a barcode, it prints "product not found" wheras it should behave like it does when you enter "12345678". I'm not sure why this is happening but I'm sure someone could tell me. Thanks

```
#"""
order = []

print("Enter a GTIN-8 product code and the quantity required. Press '/' when you're done")
print("")
while True:
    try:
        number = input("Enter GTIN: ")
        if number == "/":
            break
        else:
            if len(number) == 8:
                int(number)
                qty = input("Enter quantity: ")
                int(qty)
                order.append(number)
                order.append(qty)
                print("")
            else:
                print("Length of GTIN-8 barcode should be 8.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Only enter numbers.")
        continue

#"""



#order = ["12345678", "2", "12345670", "2", "11111111", "3", "87654321", "8"]


file = open("file.txt", "r")



count = 0
for line in file:
    product = line.split(',')
    if order[count] == product[0]:
        totalCost = float(order[1]) * float(product[2].strip('\n'))
        receipt = product[productCount], product[1], order[1], product[2].strip('\n'), str(totalCost)
        receipt = " ".join(receipt)
        print(receipt)
    else:
        print("Product not found")
    count = count + 2
    if count >= len(order):
        break
```

Comment: the problem is that you have to end the loop to be sure that your product is not found. That's currently not the case: the message will be printed, but at the next iteration, the product can be found...

Answer (score 0):

As Jean-Francois Fabre pointed out, in your for loop you are only checking the first line of the file for a match to your order, before giving up and printing Product not found. Even if you fix this, another problem is, you are looping through reading your file only once. You should refactor the code so that the outer loop of the for loop loops over the orders, the inner loop looks through the lines of the file till it finds/reaches end of the file.